# WebP format conversion for iOS SDK

Tags: ios, webp

WebP-iOS demo app is an excellent workout for converting PNG/JPG images into WebP format, but found performance issues while converting images with size above 500kb.

Has someone come across this issue? If Yes, can you please suggest a way to improve the performance?